# Redirect rules for 404 content using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

It's quite common for us to put in progress sites at `www.domain.com/dev/` and then once the client has signed off the site to move it to the top level `www.domain.com`, what we like is to be able to put a .htaccess file in the top level so that once we've moved the site out of /dev if the client accidently goes to `www.domain.com/dev/apage.php` that they be redirected to `www.domain.com/apage.php`, but only if `www.domain.com/dev/apage.php` doesn't exist.

Sometimes the dev folder will be called various other things, and ideally we don't want to have to edit the .htaccess file to match the folder name.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

*Edited based on comments:*

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule dev/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Which basically means that if the file doesn't exist - `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` -  then rewrite any request to dev back to the root. You have to specify dev/ in the rewrite rule as otherwise you will get stuck in a redirect loop.

This will only work however if you are using explicit files rather than a framework with everything routed through `index.php` for example

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a start, is it possible to rewrite this rule so it will work on any domain without having to be rewritten for each?

Comment: Check my updated example, that removes the requirement for the url to be specified

Comment: Thanks for your help, the following seems to suit my purposes quite well. `RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it helped in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?